# How to find the output node name of given .ckpt.meta file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

So far I can get the list of all node names given any .ckpt.meta file, but I was wondering if there is a systematic way of finding out the output node name from the list.

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('mymodel.ckpt.meta')
    graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
    node_list=[n.name for n in graph_def.node]
```

Comment: Generally it is useful to use namespaces to make your search easier. Also, you can use `tf.identity` to give an output of an operation a name of your liking. You can get the variable name with `graph_def.get_tensor_by_name('mynamespace/myvar:0')`. I haven't come across a better way yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    def get_node_name():
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
            graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
            name_list = []
    
            
            for node in graph_def.node:
                name_list.append(node.name)
    
            outputs = set(name_list)
    
            for index, output in enumerate(outputs):
                print('Node Name: ', output)
```

Then run:

```
get_node_name()
```