# Get input and output node name from .ckpt and .meta files tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have .meta and .ckpt files of the tensorflow model. I wanted to know exact input and output node name but I am getting a list of node names by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548765/how-to-find-the-output-node-name-of-given-ckpt-meta-file-in-tensorflow).

When I have a frozen protobuf model, I get the input node name and output node name as the starting and end of the list using this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
GRAPH_PB_PATH = 'frozen_model.pb'
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print("load graph")
   with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
   sess.graph.as_default()
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
   graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
   names = []
   for t in graph_nodes:
      names.append(t.name)
   print(names)
```

Can I do something similar for .ckpt or .meta file ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.meta` file contains information about the different node in the tensorflow [graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs#what_is_a_tfgraph). This has been better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195454/what-is-the-tensorflow-checkpoint-meta-file).

The values of the different variables in the graph at that moment are stored separately in the checkpoint folder in `checkpoint.data-xxxx-of-xxxx` file.

There is no concept of an input or output node in the normal checkpoint process, as opposed to the case of a frozen model. Freezing a model outputs a subset of the whole tensorflow graph. This subset of the main graph has only those nodes present on which the output node is dependent on. Because freezing a model is done for serving purposes, it converts the tensorflow variables to constants, eliminating the need for storing additional information like gradients of the different variables at each step.

If you still want to identify the nodes you would be interested in, you can restore your graph from the `.meta` file and visualize it in tensorboard.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.summary import FileWriter

sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.import_meta_graph("your-meta-graph-file.meta")
FileWriter("__tb", sess.graph)
```

This will create a `__tb` folder in your current directory and you can then view the graph by issuing the following command.

```sh
tensorboard --logdir __tb
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnrp5.png) is a link to the screenshot of some model with a node selected. You can get the name of the node from the top right corner.

Comment: When I run tensorboard command in my terminal all I get is http://DESKTOP-JQCP6TS:6006/ what am I suppose to do with this?

Comment: Type localhost:6006 instead (after running the tensorboard command). It should take you to the tensorboard.