# Want to know the list of the inputs and outputs along with the shape of a tensorflow model checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I have the model checkpoint file along with the `.index` and `.meta` files but i want to know what are the inputs and outputs for the model along with the dimensions and shape for each of them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757380/get-input-and-output-node-name-from-ckpt-and-meta-files-tensorflow), the checkpoint save doesn't have strictly defined inputs and outputs (in contrast to the frozen graph). Still, you can inspect your graph with `TensorBoard` and identify input and output tensors:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.summary import FileWriter

sess = tf.Session()
tf.train.import_meta_graph("your-meta-graph-file.meta")
FileWriter("__tb", sess.graph)
```

and inspect it with `tensorboard --logdir __tb`.